# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.url'

Tags: django

I was creating my django first app. I added this code

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.url'))
]
```

from my project **urls.py** file to get my html code from my app **url.py**, but i keep getting this error when i want to run my server.

> *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.url'*

Comment: It's `myapp.urls` (with an `s`).

Comment: i also did myapp.urls, its still showing that errors "No module name 'myapp.urls'

Comment: add ```app_name="mayapp"``` inside your app urls.py file.

Comment: Have you added `myapp` into your settings `INSTALLED_APPS` section?